# Error mounting HD

Tags: partitioning, mount, hibernate

I've got 4 HD, 1 SSD for the system and 3 SATA HD for data.
I had some problems with Windows and I decided to format my system HD (without partitions) and install just Ubuntu.
I've installed Ubuntu, and now it can mount only 1 HD. For the other 2 HD I received the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/arberto/Robetta new: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/arberto/Robetta new"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I've read a lot of questions and answers about my problem, but everyone say to deactivate hibernation in Windows 8... but I have no more Windows 8!

I read it could be related to a file, hiberfile.sys. How can I delete it?
I don't care about not saved sessions, and after all they are only data disks.

I've already do that:
[Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)
But I want to write on that disks, and I don't want to mount them every time I start my pc.

Comment: The problem was that when you were using windows you didn't shutdown windows or unmounted the partitions when you removed windows. I would mount with the read-only access, copy the data somewhere, then nuke the disk. Otherwise you will keep the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

"The disk contains an unclean file system"
It appears the disk is not formatted correctly. I would recommend using
Gparted. Download it from Ubuntu Software Manager then run it and go to 
that disk. Remove any partitions on it. Then create a single partition 
using the entire disk and format it!
The disk probably still has a UEFI boot and formatting on it from the 
Windows 8 install and Gparted can correct that.

Comment: Actually the disks are pretty full, and I have no partitions for them... If I format I'll lose all my data, and I need it.

Comment: Do a search for EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition. It is a free program and you will be able to fix your MBR and retrieve everything as well. I have used it quite a few times and it worked perfectly every time.